# What is the .NET equivalent of Apple's CoreData?

Tags: .net, core-data, orm, domain-model

I am studying up on domain model and OR/M frameworks. I am familiar with Apple's CoreData, and would like to know: What Microsoft product is the equivalent to Apple's CoreData?

Comment: Please leave an explanation rather than simply -1'ing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to say it's [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) (EF).

Per the MSDN site regarding Entity Framework:

> Entity Framework (EF) is an object-relational mapper that enables .NET developers to work with relational data using domain-specific objects. It eliminates the need for most of the data-access code that developers usually need to write.

However, unlike CoreData which I believe works for OS X and iOS, I don't believe EF works on Windows Mobile phones yet, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: Even if it does work on mobile platforms, you probably shouldn't be doing direct database access from there anyways.